# Simple $HTTP_POST_FILES nor $_FILES does not work - PHP

Tags: php

I have done file upload many times, but got no idea on why this is not working.  Trying to do a file desc before upload but neither $HTTP_POST_FILES nor $_FILES does not seem to work.

```
  echo "Upload: " . $HTTP_POST_FILES["profilefilepic"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $HTTP_POST_FILES["profilefilepic"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($HTTP_POST_FILES["profilefilepic"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $HTTP_POST_FILES["profilefilepic"]["tmp_name"];


<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="changeorder" id="changeorder" value="Upload">
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40" id="profilefilepic" name="profilefilepic">
<input type="hidden" name="profilefilepicname" id="profilefilepicname" value="">
</form>
```

What is wrong here.

Comment: Don't forget the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part in the form tag

Comment: Related note: `$HTTP_POST_FILES` has been deprecated for many years (since PHP/4.1.0).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Sometimes it is not the reading, its just the overlooking.

Answer (score 6):

add `enctype` to your form

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Use only one `name` attribute to your input filetype, like:

```
<input type="file" name="profilefilepic" size="40" id="profilefilepic" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 "name" attributes in the `file` input, and you're missing the `enctype` to your form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="profilefilepic" name="profilefilepic">
```

Answer (score 0):

Two missing stuffs

1. `<input type="file" id="profilefilepic" name="profilefilepic">`
2. `<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Thanks

Sudhir and Proreborn